# Symfony JMS Serializer deserialize array of jsons to an entitie

Tags: php, symfony, deserialization, json-deserialization, jmsserializerbundle

I have this string:

```
[{
    "box": [{
        "UID": "bid1106"
    }, {
        "UID": "bid565"
    }, {
        "UID": "bid1105"
    }]
}, {
    "topseller": [{
        "UID": "pid1816z1"
    }, {
        "UID": "pid8840z100z06"
    }, {
        "UID": "pid2942z01z18"
    }, {
        "UID": "pid5863z0"
    }]
}, {
    "global": {
        "templatename": "homepage",
        "locationid": "",
        "controlgroup": "false"
    }
}]
```

I need somehow to make Object using JMS serializer.

```
$obj = $this->serializer->deserialize($jsonData, ObjectClass::class, 'json');
```

And my ObjectClass.php class looks like this

```
class ObjectClass
{
    private $box = [];
    private $topseller = [];
    private $global = [];
    ....
}
```

Any suggestions, how I can make it as a single Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figure it out by my self:

```
    $newArray =[];
    foreach (json_decode($jsonData, true) as $item) {
        $key = array_keys($item)[0];
        $newArray[$key] = $item[$key];
    }


    $obj = $this->serializer->deserialize(json_encode($newArray), ObjectClass::class, 'json');
```